# How to use an tensorflow Function Model to define its partialy model?

Tags: python

there is a model called transformer1 I want to do that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o00X.png)
and that is the model after[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIdv6.png)
why I cannot input (None,1088) into it. but it still return an error like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJcww.png) or how to do it?

emmmm I want to run it without error. (Since I want to make a manifold mixup but I don't know how to apply it to tf.Functional Model. if you can give me another way to solve it.)

Answer (score 0):

sorry I do wrong at callbacks2 function. After I revise the callbacks2 function  use after to replace the model "m" it can be done correctly.